# Expected value and variance of random variable of bus

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

> The bus company has $m$ bus. The bus had two side mirrors. In the streets of Munich, each of the $2m$ mirrors breaks oﬀ independently with probability $p$. Let $n$ be the total number of broken mirrors, $L$ be the number of cars with a broken left mirror, $R$ be the number of cars with a broken right mirror, and $x$ be the number of cars with no mirrors.
>
> 1. The expected value of $L$ and variance $R$.
> 2. The expected value and variance of $n$.
> 3. The expected value and variance of $x$.
> 4. The expected value and variance of $L-R$.

I have no idea with the remaining and I am not really sure is my answer is logical.

1. This should be a binominal distribution so the expected value should be $Lp$ and variance is $L^2p-(Lp)^2$.
2. Expected value is $np$ and the variance is $np(1-p)$.

Comment: $L$ is a random variable so cannot appear in expressions for $\mathbb EL$ and $\text{Var}L$ in parameters.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints** (on how to compute the expected values):

In both of your answers, the expected value of your variable depends on the variable itself, which is not satisfactory.

1. For each of the $m$ buses, flip one coin that comes up heads with probability $p$. If you get a heads, the left mirror is broken. How many do you expect to be broken after you've flipped one coin for each bus?
2. The $2m$ mirrors break off with probability $p$, so we'd expect there to be $E(n)=\dots$ broken mirrors.
3. Now flip two coins for each bus. If *both* comes up heads, both the mirrors are broken. What is the probability of this?
4. Use linearity of expectation.

For the variance part, have you tried applying [the definition of the variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition)?

Comment: if I flip the coin again to be head the prob is p^2,but if I know the fist one then the next one is p again so its equal to mp? does you mean that I should look the left and right  mirror as independent mirror so I would have m mirrors on the left side and m mirror on the right side.since their prob to be broken are same and independent so the left side is mp and right side is also mp

Comment: I mean that the prob. of a bus having both mirrors broken is simply $p^2$, as you noted. I'm not sure what you mean by the rest of your comment - could you perhaps rephrase?

Comment: sorry for my poor English. I mean that to solve this problem is to treat the left and right mirror separately. It means I have m mirrors on the left m mirrors on the right. Since the break off prob is independently therefore if follows the binominal distribution

Comment: @Ccnoc Yes, that sounds correct. If you want to be sure, perhaps post your solution(s).

Answer (score 0):

In cases 1,2,3 you are dealing with binomial distribution.

- 1) Parameters $m$ and $p$
- 2) Parameters $2m$ and $p$
- 3) Parameters $m$ and $p^2$

---

- 4)

$L$ and $R$ have the same binomial distribution. Moreover $L$ and $R$ are independent as well (the breaking off of a window at one side has no influence on the breaking off of a window at the other side).

Can you find the expectation and variance of $L-R$ yourself? Remember that the variance of the sum of two independent variables equalizes the sum of the involved variances.